# PHPExcel Worksheet!A2 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,

Tags: escaping, formula, phpexcel

After few hours spend on the PHPExcel error **Worksheet!A2 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,** I found out that

```
$sheet->setCellValue($col . $row, $value);
```

throws me this error if I try to insert string **=ER=, s.r.o.** into the cell. As I removed first = sign it start to work. However weird it looks =ER= is the name of real company. And I want to write it as a string into the cell.

The question is **which signs and how should be escaped** to avoid this behavior of PHPExcel? I expected PHPExcel will escape this cases. Like whet I send data to DB...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to start the cell with a single quote `'` to avoid that leading equal sign being treated as the start of a sum. Use:

```
$sheet->setCellValue($col . $row, "'" . $value);
```

If the quote causes problems for other values like dates and number you can test `$value` to see if it starts with `=` and, if it does add the single quotes otherwise leave it alone.

```
$sheet->setCellValue($col . $row,(substr($value,0,1) == '=' ? "'" . $value : $value));
```

Comment: But what about another values like dates or numbers? Can it be enclosed by " " without affecting its excel format?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question but if it causes problems you could always test the first character of `$value` and if it is `=` add the quotes. I'll modify my answer to reflect that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it is only HOT FIX and I need to find clear solid solution.

Comment: Not sure why you think that isn't a solid solution. Cells that start with an equal sign are interpreted by Excel differently and that isn't likely to change. You may want to switch to PHPSpreadSheet and see if it handles things differently since PHPExcel hasn't been updated in going on 5 years and is deprecated.

Comment: And just so you know, Excel itself will NOT allow a cell that starts with an equal sign without it being prefixed by a single quote `'`. Amending my answer with the new information.

Comment: In my case, I am facing this error " Formula Error: Unexpected operator '&' ", but in my file, there is no formula. Don't get any workable solution through the internet

Comment: @NazmulHasanSheum Start a new question with the details of your problem. Just based on your comment it sounds like your data contains an ampersand and it is not properly quoted so it looks like a string.

Answer (score 1):

Proper solution is using setCellValueExplicit function:

[Documention](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/39534e3dd376041d0d50a4714e73375bf45b692b/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md) includes a following example:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit(
'A8', 
"01513789642",
PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING
);
```